# Techanjs zoom freez in updating chart

Tags: d3.js, techan.js

I am using Techanjs to create updating candlestick chart, the example I am referring is => http://bl.ocks.org/andredumas/95f1f22130fb1a3a8181
This example doesn't support zoom so from another example => http://bl.ocks.org/andredumas/a48008ea8e2c832144db I copied the code for zoom. 
 
 My chart is zooming now but now the issue I am facing is the zoom got reset to the original zoom level when the new candle gets added in the chart. current code

```
function zoomed() {
var rescaledY = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(y);
yAxis.scale(rescaledY);
candlestick.yScale(rescaledY);
```

Code I tried:

```
function zoomed() {
let t = d3.zoomTransform( svg.node());
var rescaledY = t.rescaleY(y);
yAxis.scale(rescaledY);
candlestick.yScale(rescaledY);
```

below line is present where I am reading the json

`zoomableInit = x.zoomable().clamp(false).copy();`

To freeze the zoom I tried to modify the rescaleY and rescaleX functions but didn't really understand the required changes. Please suggest.

Comment: Can you please add a snippet, that would help addressing your issue.

Comment: @Ma'mounothman I have added the code snippet for reference.